# django condition for adding multiple files

Tags: django, python-2.7

I have an option of adding upto 5 files.

I am having a manual form, in which i have a field to upload file.

```
**models.py**
class resmodel(models.Model):
user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)
fname = models.CharField(max_length=20)

file1 = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
file2 = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
file3 = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
file4 = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')

file_header1 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
file_header2 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
file_header3 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
file_header4 = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

When i submit the form for first time, the uploaded file and its corresponding file_header  got saved into file1 and file_header respectively..

Similarly
When i submit the form for second time, i have to check whether the file1 was filled, if not  the uploaded file have to be saved into file1, else it should be saved to file2.

When i submit the form for third time, i have to check whether the file1 and file2 was filled, if not  the uploaded file have to be saved into file1 or in file 2 whichever empty, else it should be saved to file2.

Ans so on upto file5.

```
**views.py**
def resview(request):
if request.method == "POST":
    upload_resume = request.FILES['upload_resume']
    file_header = request.POST.get('resume_header')
    fname = request.POST.get('fname')

    if upload_resume:
        details, _ = resmodel.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        if not details.file1:
            details.file1 = upload_resume
        elif not details.file2:
            details.file2 = upload_resume
        elif not details.file3:
            details.file3 = upload_resume
        elif not details.file4:
            details.file4 = upload_resume
        details.save()

    if upload_resume:
        details, _ = resmodel.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)
        if not details.file_header2:
            details.file_header1 = file_header
        elif not details.file_header2:
            details.file_header2 = file_header
        elif not details.file_header3:
            details.file_header3 = file_header
        elif not details.file_header4:
            details.file_header4 = file_header
        details.save()

    a = resmodel(fname=fname)
    a.save()
    return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/save/success/')
else:
    return render_to_response('resume.html')
```

and my template is

```
<form action="." method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">{% csrf_token %}
<table>
    <tr>
    <td>First Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="fname" /></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>File Header<sub>(250 words max)</sub></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="file_header"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td>Upload file<sub>(.doc/.docx, rtf, pdf, txt)</sub></td>
    <td><input type="file" name="upload_resume" ></td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <td></td>
    <td>
        <input type="submit" value="SUBMIT">&nbsp;&nbsp;
        <input type="reset" value="RESET">
    </td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
def resview(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        upload_resume = request.FILES['upload_resume']
        file_header = request.POST.get('resume_header')
        fname = request.POST.get('fname')

        if upload_resume and file_header:
            details, _ = resmodel.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user, fname=fname)
            if not details.file1:
                details.file1 = upload_resume
                details.file_header1 = file_header
            elif not details.file2:
                details.file2 = upload_resume
                details.file_header2 = file_header
            elif not details.file3:
                details.file3 = upload_resume
                details.file_header3 = file_header
            elif not details.file4:
                details.file4 = upload_resume
                details.file_header4 = file_header
            details.save()

        return HttpResponseRedirect('/profile/save/success/')
    else:
        return render_to_response('resume.html')
```

Comment: May i know, whats that "details, _" represents?

Comment: I am getting this error ""int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'SimpleLazyObject'""

Comment: Now I see lots of errors in your codes. Wait I will update my answer

Comment: Since i am new to this field, i found little bit tough. Dnt mistake me, if i do or did silly errors.

Comment: Thanks, Superb it works good. Can i get an alert, if i try to add more than 5 files.

Answer (score 1):

What you need is an extra model.

```
class js_details(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, unique=True)

class js_details_file(models.Model):
    js_details = models.ForeignKey(js_details)
    file = models.FileField(upload_to='documents')
```

Then use [Inlines](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/admin/#inlinemodeladmin-objects) in your admin interface to allow uploading of files, and use [Formsets](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/forms/formsets/) on the frontend.